# Pixel manipulation with SDL surface?

Tags: c, pixel, sdl-2

I'm trying to play around with image manipulation in C and I want to be able to read and write pixels on an SDL Surface. (I'm loading a bmp to a surface to get the pixel data) I'm having some trouble figuring out how to properly use the following functions.

```
SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom();
SDL_GetRGB();
SDL_MapRGB();
```

I have only found examples of these in c++ and I'm having a hard time implementing it in C because I don't fully understand how they work.

so my questions are:

1. how do you properly retrieve pixel data using GetRGB? + How is the pixel addressed with x, y cordinates?
2. What kind of array would I use to store the pixel data?
3. How do you use SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom() to draw the new pixel data back to a surface?

Also I want to access the pixels individually in a nested for loop for y and x like so.

```
for(int y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
     // get/put the pixel data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at [SDL_Surface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface).

**The parts you're interested in:**

- [`SDL_PixelFormat`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat)`*format`
- `int w, h`
- `int pitch`
- `void *pixels`

**What else you should know:**

On position x, y (which must be greater or equal to 0 and less than w, h) the surface contains a pixel.
The pixel is described by the `format` field, which tells us, how the pixel is organized in memory.

The [Remarks](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat#remarks) section of [SDL_PixelFormat](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat) gives more information on the used datatype.

The `pitch` field is basically the width of the surface multiplied by the size of the pixel (`BytesPerPixel`).

With the function [SDL_GetRGB](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRGB), one can easily convert a pixel of any format to a RGB(A) triple/quadruple.
[SDL_MapRGB](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MapRGB) is the reverse of [SDL_GetRGB](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRGB), where one can specify a pixel as RGB(A) triple/quadruple to map it to the closest color specified by the `format` parameter.

The SDL wiki provides many examples of the specific functions, i think you will find the proper examples to solve your problem.